# PerformancePoint scorecard drill down

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, dashboard, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I have a scorecard with hierarchy in PerformancePoint dashboard. 
By default everything is expanded (drilled down to the lowest level), is there any way I can prevent this, so when I load a scorecard everything will be collapsed (not drilled down) ?

*Default:*

[image: Default]

*Desired:*

[image: Desired]

Comment: Many solutions are suggesting "all children" instead of "all descendants" however when leveraging a hierarchy this is limiting to the "all children" is limiting to one level of the hierarchy. "All descendants" is encapsulating the desired data, though it seems there is no way to represent this via dashboard designer with a default "collapsed" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Select "all children" instead of "all descendants".

Atleast that did the trick for me when creating charts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the dimension column of the Scorecard.
2. Click **Select Members**
3. Select **Children of "All"** as shown in image below.
4. Click OK
5. Save

**Caution:** If you expand any member and save, the score card will also appear expanded.
How you see the scorecard in Dashboard Designer, it will appear exactly the same in the Browser.

Thanks,
Merin

Answer (score -1):

When you view the scorecard from dashboard designer, All you need to do is unexpand which levels you do not want to show. This will create a default for all your viewers to see.